# Can a Listview be divided into two?

Tags: android, android-listview

I was making an application which uses list for displaying the details of a employee in a way like this:

```
Name                  :   abcd
Age                   :   28
Phone No              :   1234567890.
```

I had designed with 2 listviews and my listview like (side by side as shown above),

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <ListView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:id="@+id/list_unit_main"/>
        <ListView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:id="@+id/list_unit_main"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

For first list I added an arrayadapter and it displays name, age and phone number tags. Now I just want to know that is it possible to make a list divided into 2? 
Or do I have to make another list for displaying details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the answer. Here it is. I think it would be helpful for others.
In my row layout I created a new xml file named *mylist.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/FirstColumn" 
        android:paddingTop="2dip" 
        android:paddingBottom="2dip" 
        android:textSize="7pt"
        android:layout_width="180dip" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/SecondColumn" 
        android:paddingTop="2dip" 
        android:paddingBottom="2dip" 
        android:textSize="7pt"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And I wrote an adapter java file which details my list view:

```
package com.converter;

import static com.converter.Constant.FIRST_COLUMN;
import static com.converter.Constant.SECOND_COLUMN;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import android.app.Activity;

public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    public ArrayList<HashMap<String , String>> list;
    Activity activity;

    public ListViewAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<HashMap<String  , String>> list)
    {
        super();
        this.activity=activity;
        this.list=list;
    }

    public int getCount()
    {
        return list.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position)
    {
        return list.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    private class ViewHolder
    {
        TextView txt_first, txt_Second;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertview, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        ViewHolder holder;
        LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();

        if(convertview == null)
        {
            convertview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylist, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.txt_first = (TextView)convertview.findViewById(R.id.FirstColumn);
            holder.txt_Second = (TextView)convertview.findViewById(R.id.SecondColumn);
            convertview.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder)convertview.getTag();
        }
        HashMap<String, String> map = list.get(position);
        holder.txt_first.setText(map.get(FIRST_COLUMN));
        holder.txt_Second.setText(map.get(SECOND_COLUMN));

        return convertview;
    }
}
```

And another class to specify constants in my program, *constant.java*

package com.converter;

```
public class Constant 
{
    public static final String FIRST_COLUMN = "First";
    public static final String SECOND_COLUMN = "Second";
}
```

while in my *main.xml* file, I have

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <ListView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:id="@+id/list_main"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Right now I have my own layout for my listview in *mylist.xml* and need to put that view on the listview of *main.xml*.

Then, in my activity file I have:

```
ListView list_activity = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_main);

//got adapter for mylistview(for my first column) 
//and called a function to populate as my needed view....
//do that by urself...

public void populateList(ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adpt, int pos,int pos2)
    {
        list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
        double[] array = getArray(pos, pos2);//was my for my pgm for a calulation
        for(int i = 0; i < adpt.getCount();i++)
        {
            String str = adpt.getItem(i).toString();

            HashMap<String, String> temp = new HashMap<String, String>();
            temp.put(FIRST_COLUMN, str);
            temp.put(SECOND_COLUMN, Double.toString(array[i]));
            list.add(temp);
        }
        ListViewAdapter adapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, list);
        list_activity.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no need of two list view. A good example of ListView with multiple columns is shown at [this link](http://www.technotalkative.com/android-multi-column-listview/).

Answer (score 2):

java:

```
ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.some_list);

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("first", "Name");
map.put("second", ":");
map.put("third", "abcd");
mylist.add(map);
map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("first", "Age");
map.put("second", ":");
map.put("third", "28");
mylist.add(map);

columnAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist, R.layout.row,
            new String[] {"first", "second", "third"}, new int[] {R.id.first_cell, R.id.second_cell, R.id.third_cell});
list.setAdapter(columnAdapter);
```

xml1:

```
<LinearLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="horizontal">

     <TextView android:id="@+id/first_cell"
         android:layout_width="50dip"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

     <TextView android:id="@+id/second_cell"
         android:layout_width="70dip"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"/>

     <TextView android:id="@+id/third_cell"
         android:layout_width="60dip"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"  android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

xml2:

```
<ListView android:id="@+id/some_list" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</ListView>
```

And then populate mylist programmatically using some conditional expression

Answer (score 1):

For this, you don't need 2 list views. You will just need a single listview with a custom adapter to show whatever you need. You can refer to this example.

http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2009/07/custom-listview-for-android.html

Answer (score 0):

You need not to take two listview. You have to use custom list by using adapter.

you have to design a list element as you want.